# How to get font name like in the Windows Registry with C#?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, fonts, registry

### First Try

Here is what we get for the Arial TTF font:

[image]

Here is what we get for the Sitka TTC font:

[image]

And here is what we get for the SimSun TTC font:

[image]

I tried to use the `OpenFontReader` object from the [Typography.OpenFont.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Typography.OpenFont.NetCore/) package.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Typography.OpenFont;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fontName1 = GetRegistryFontName(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf");
            var fontName2 = GetRegistryFontName(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Sitka.ttc");
            var fontName3 = GetRegistryFontName(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\simsun.ttc");

            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string GetRegistryFontName(string fontFile)
        {
            var fontReader = new OpenFontReader();
            var fontInfo = fontReader.ReadPreview(File.OpenRead(fontFile));

            var fontExtension = Path.GetExtension(fontFile).ToLower();
            var fontTypeSuffix = (fontExtension == ".otc" || fontExtension == ".otf") ? "(OpenType)" : "(TrueType)";

            if (fontExtension == ".otf" || fontExtension == ".ttf")
            {
                return $"{fontInfo.Name} {fontInfo.SubFamilyName} {fontTypeSuffix}";
            }
            else if (fontExtension == ".otc" || fontExtension == ".ttc")
            {
                var fontNames = fontInfo.Name.Split(",").Skip(1).ToArray();
                var result = new StringBuilder(fontNames[0]);

                foreach (var fontName in fontNames[1..^1])
                {
                    result.Append($" & {fontName}");
                }

                result.Append($" & {fontNames[^1]} {fontTypeSuffix}");

                return result.ToString();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

It's almost working but there are two problems:

- The name for the `arial.ttf` font is `Arial (TrueType)` in the Registry and `Arial Normal (TrueType)` in my result.
- I get an Asian name for the `simsun.ttc` font with `OpenFontReader`.

---

### Second Try

I tried using the fontview and the [FlaUI](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI) package.

```cs
using FlaUI.Core;
using FlaUI.Core.Tools;
using FlaUI.UIA3;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fontName1 = GetRegistryFontName(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf");

            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static string GetRegistryFontName(string fontFile)
        {
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "fontview",
                Arguments = fontFile
            };

            string fontName = null;
            var app = Application.Launch(psi);
            using (var automation = new UIA3Automation())
            {
                var window = Retry.WhileNull(() =>
                    app.GetMainWindow(automation),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
                ).Result;

                window.SetTransparency(0);
                window.Focus();

                fontName = window.Title;

                window.Close();
            }

            return fontName;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is even more weird:

[image]

The Arial font is now an OpenType font. Thank you Windows. :)

---

Do you have a solution to recover the same name as in the Registry?
It should work with any font even external ones and with .NET Core.

Comment: Why just don't read the values from registry directly? Package [description](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Typography.OpenFont.NetCore/) tells you _EXTREMELY UNSTABLE AND LIKELY TO FAIL. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK_

Comment: Yes I know about the warning. I can't use the Registry because I would like to get the font name from any font, even ones that are not installed.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand why so many people say Windows is an abomination. ;)

Comment: Please clarify: You're trying to get the font _file name_? How will you be using the name once you get it? (That will help clarify what type of name you should be trying to get.)