# How to retrieve font information like in the new Windows Font Settings from C#?

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, fonts

I would like to get font information like in the new Windows Font Settings from C# and .NET Core.

[image]

How to get Full name, Font file, Version, and so on in C# and use it from a console project.

```cs
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var info = GetFontInfo(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf");

            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static object GetFontInfo(string fontFilePath)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

I can get the proper information with `GlyphTypeface`  in a WPF application.

```cs
GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\JetBrainsMono-Regular.ttf", UriKind.Absolute));
var name = glyphTypeface.FamilyNames.Values.First();
var version = glyphTypeface.VersionStrings.Values.First();
```

Comment: You've already asked the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017050/how-to-get-font-name-like-in-the-windows-registry-with-c)

Comment: It's not quite the same question.

Comment: You can use `FontFamily` class, but it's WPF/WinForms related

Comment: Yes there is `GlyphTypeface` too but how to use it from a dotnet console application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve Filename of a font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21525377/retrieve-filename-of-a-font)

Comment: I don't think it works with external fonts.